# Does members only content get penalized? 1000+ Pages, 1 to 2 Hits a Day

Tags: seo, google, penalty

I have been rolling out several online courses which combined have 1000+ pages.  The videos are restricted, but the text and headers aren't.  These pages have been indexed for a few months now but aren't generating any traffic.  I haven't started building backlinks yet, so maybe that's it, but I'm wondering if I'm being penalized by Google for restricting the video content.

I kinda assumed that I'd at least be seeing a trickle of traffic from 1000+ pages, but I'm lucky right now if I get 1-2 hits a day...  The whole site combined with blog posts etc. gets between 4 and 10 a day.

Comment: It takes a quite a while to get traffic and organic back links are a huge part of that. It is an up-hill climb. Pay special attention to on-page SEO. But you may want to consider a scheme of some sort where the videos are behind a log-in on a separate page away from Google's eyes. That way you are eliminating a questionable issue to know for sure. I am not sure how Google would handle the situation you described.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you should ask yourself is "**Are these pages relevant enough to get indexed?**"

If you have a good title and a fair amount of content, the page should be interessing enough to get indexed. What if ***I*** go to your page now, will it be interesting enough to for me?

Might want to read:  [First Click Free for Web Search](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2008/10/first-click-free-for-web-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are users that land on these pages going to be satisfied with the pages even though they can't see the videos?    Google pays a lot of attention to user behavior.   If all the users that Google sends end up using the back button and clicking on another result, your pages are not going to rank well.  Google generally tries out pages like this and then determines that users don't like them and it stops ranking them or deindexes them altogether.

These pages may even be hurting the rest of your site.   Having many pages with poor usability reflects poorly on your site as a whole.   Having many such pages is one of the factors that that may cause Google's Panda algorithm to penalize your site.

Answer (score -1):

Start linkbuilding. 
People hardly find your site via Google and no visitors via backlinks. 1 or 2 hits a day is even much then:)
Don't hide all your content/video's. Show at least some (preferrably much) complete course examples, so people know your courses are valueble.
Pages with hidden content, don't let them indexed.
Search and read for "SEO". There is much nonsense on the net, but soon you will understand the difference between usefull and nonsense. 
Use an affiliate system to reward related sites sending traffic to you. (assuming you earn something with the courses.)